# FUNCTION ST_Distance_Sphere does not exist in MariaDB

Tags: database, mariadb, latitude-longitude

I want get all locations around my location but the function `ST_Distance_Sphere` does not work.

My query:

```
select *, astext(location) as location from `locations`
where ST_Distance_Sphere(location, POINT(35.905069591297, 49.765869174153)) < 1000
```

Error :

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:
1305 FUNCTION app.ST_Distance_Sphere does not exist (SQL:
select *, astext(location) as location from `locations`
where ST_Distance_Sphere(location, POINT(35.905069591297, 49.765869174153)) < 1000)
```

Comment: My DataBase is MariaDb

Comment: The formula with lots of trig calls works MySQL or MariaDB.  MySQL only recently (5.7.6) implemented that ST function; MariaDB does not seem to have picked it up yet.

Comment: i see this link but ST_Distance_Sphere function is not Similar !

[MariaDb Docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mysqlmariadb-spatial-support-matrix/)

Comment: The formulas need latitudes and longitudes.  But that is what your `POINT` is composed of, correct?  I am suggesting a somewhat messy workaround, not a simple drop-in replacement.

Comment: I angry From MariaDB :|
i change DataBase to PostgreSQL ! :|

Answer (score 16):

For those who still need the function in MariaDB, you can create the function based on the formula

```
    CREATE FUNCTION `st_distance_sphere`(`pt1` POINT, `pt2` POINT) RETURNS 
    decimal(10,2)
    BEGIN
    return 6371000 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(
       POWER(SIN((ST_Y(pt2) - ST_Y(pt1)) * pi()/180 / 2),
       2) + COS(ST_Y(pt1) * pi()/180 ) * COS(ST_Y(pt2) *
       pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((ST_X(pt2) - ST_X(pt1)) *
       pi()/180 / 2), 2) ));
    END
```

Comment: I had to delete "BEGIN". Also, I guess a spatial index does not work with this function. Correct?

Comment: @moritz.vieli .True, BEGIN is not required for single line routine. As long as indexes are used on base tables, the functions can be used in Views, Stored Procedures, or Triggers. Or what do you mean?

Comment: Let's assume, I have a SELECT statement where I sort by st_distance_sphere. Does MariaDB use the spatial index I added on a column, which is used as a parameter for the function?

Comment: well, obviously not with this self-implemented function, rendering the spatial index in mariadb completely useless.

Answer (score 9):

## 10.2+

This issue has been fixed and backported with [MDEV-13467](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13467). It's available 10.2.38, 10.3.29, 10.4.19, 10.5.10

Find [their support matrix here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysqlmariadb-spatial-support-matrix/).

Comment: Update - ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE is finally available in MariaDB after 10.2! Thank you for posting the link to the issue, where the issue is now "closed"

Comment: @flexponsive updated, thanks

Comment: I'm using 10.3.22-MariaDB on a Debian 10 server and still got "st_distance_sphere does not exist"

Answer (score 1):

http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql#gcdistdeg

That blog discusses multiple ways of "finding nearest" on the globe in MySQL/MariaDB.  As part of that discussion, I developed that Stored Function.

Answer (score -3):

I think that's it `ST_DISTANCE`  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/st_distance/

Comment: That's for flat geometry, not for sphere one.