# MariaDB no equivalent function for ST_Distance_Sphere

Tags: mysql, geometry, mariadb, geospatial

In MySQL 5.7 there is a function called `ST_Distance_Sphere` which can be used to find points within a radius e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE `places` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `coordinates` point DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `places` ( `name`, `coordinates`)
VALUES ("Eiffel Tower", POINT(48.858271, 2.293795));

INSERT INTO `places` ( `name`, `coordinates`)
VALUES ("Pere Lachaise", POINT(48.861131, 2.394683));

INSERT INTO `places` ( `name`, `coordinates`)
VALUES ("Brooklyn", POINT(40.711089, -73.948391));
```

If we want to see all points that are less than 10km from the Louvre which is in the center of Paris, we can do:

```
SELECT name FROM places
WHERE ST_Distance_Sphere(coordinates, POINT(48.861105, 2.335337)) < 10000
```

However no such function is supported in MariaDB 10.1+

How can I recreate the same function or recreate the same query in MariaDB. The following post shows one method of recreating the same function [FUNCTION ST_Distance_Sphere does not exist in MariaDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44409012/function-st-distance-sphere-does-not-exist-in-mariadb)?

Maybe something like this?

```
SELECT name FROM places
WHERE ST_Within(
   coordinates, ST_Buffer(POINT(48.861105, 2.335337), 10000)
);
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: The second most watched issue and second highest vote [MDEV-13467](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13467). Complain loudly.

Comment: @danblack is the function shown on the following post correct? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44409012/function-st-distance-sphere-does-not-exist-in-mariadb

Comment: @danblack I need an interim solution because that feature request will take ages and then having to wait until hosting provider offers the new db version.

Comment: I don't actually know. I'd check with some against MySQL using https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0 to check. Appreciate the urgent need. A small amount of time to request improvements from your service provider or MariaDB is an investment in improving software maintainability.

Comment: A targeted donation to MariaDB may move https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13467 up in priority.

Comment: Looks like ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE is available since MariaDB 10.2.38, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/st_distance_sphere/

Answer (score 2):

Based on the suggestions of @adam78 and @Rick James
I solved this way:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION st_distance_sphere(pt1 POINT, pt2 POINT)
RETURNS double(10,2)

RETURN 6371000 * 2 * ASIN(
    SQRT(
        POWER(SIN((ST_Y(pt2) - ST_Y(pt1)) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) +
        COS(ST_Y(pt1) * pi()/180 ) *
        COS(ST_Y(pt2) * pi()/180) *
        POWER(SIN((ST_X(pt2) - ST_X(pt1)) * pi()/180 / 2), 2)
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I provide a workaround in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql -- However, it works with a pair of numeric columns of `latitude` and `longitude` instead of `POINTs`.  (Those can be extracted from a `POINT()`.)

The main purpose of that link is your 'next' question -- how to speed up the filtering by distance.  It discusses 5 approaches.  (Your code is still at the least performant one.)

Comment: the following seems to work albiet not as fast as st_distance_sphere: `CREATE FUNCTION `st_distance_sphere`(`pt1` POINT, `pt2` POINT) RETURNS decimal(10,2) BEGIN return 6371000 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((ST_Y(pt2) - ST_Y(pt1)) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) + COS(ST_Y(pt1) * pi()/180 ) * COS(ST_Y(pt2) * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((ST_X(pt2) - ST_X(pt1)) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )); END`

Comment: @adam78 - Suggest using `DOUBLE` instead of `DECIMAL`.  And see `RADIANS()`.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem.
Use ST_DISTANCE
link : https://mariadb.com/kb/en/st_distance/
Simple example:

```
SELECT ST_DISTANCE(POINT(x y),POINT(x1 y1));
```

Returns the unit of your coordinates.

Comment: Please add code snippets to answers along with the links