# How to add ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE function to Doctrine?

Tags: function, symfony, doctrine, distance

I need to make some changes to the code, which was written by another developer. One of them is to use the ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE function in a query. I added this function to the database following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44409012/function-st-distance-sphere-does-not-exist-in-mariadb)

But I realized that it's not enough, cause the application is using Doctrine. I'm not using Doctrine in my usual applications, so I'm not pretty sure what should I do.

Until now I ran `composer require creof/doctrine2-spatial` in console

And I added to `config/package/doctrine.yaml` below code

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
        types:   
            geometry:   CrEOF\Spatial\DBAL\Types\GeometryType
            point: CrEOF\Spatial\DBAL\Types\Geometry\PointType
```

What should I do more to be able to use this function in my Repository? Error, which I'm getting is:

```
Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException:
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 70: Error: Expected known function, got 'ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE'

at vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException.php:54
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@Nicodemuz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560318/nicodemuz) answer I finally find the right way:

```
orm:
      dql:
            numeric_functions:
                stdistance: CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\Mysql\STDistance
                stdistancesphere: CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\Mysql\STDistanceSphere
                distance:               CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\Distance
                geometrytype:           CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\GeometryType
                point:                  CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\Point
```

The second important thing was that I had to use in my query `STDistanceSphere` name instead of `ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE` to make it work fine.

Third thing, it may be helpful for MySql users like me to see [this](https://github.com/creof/doctrine2-spatial/pull/191). It looks like this function is available for MySql, but it's not merged, so you should add to package some files from [here](https://github.com/0x6368/doctrine2-spatial/tree/master/lib/CrEOF/Spatial/ORM/Query/AST/Functions/MySql) .

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message, you may need something like:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
        types:   
            geometry:   CrEOF\Spatial\DBAL\Types\GeometryType
            point: CrEOF\Spatial\DBAL\Types\Geometry\PointType

    orm:
        dql:
            numeric_functions:
                # for postgresql
                stdistance:              CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\PostgreSql\STDistance
```